# Compile error despite override

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, polymorphism, overriding

Sorry if this is such an easy question, there must be something I don't understand about inheritance, `virtual` and `override` in c++. In the following example, I get a compile-time error relative to a virtual method that I specifically override to avoid such error in a child class. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <array>
#include <deque>

template <class T, class C>
struct foo
{
    virtual const C& data() const =0;

    inline virtual T& operator[] ( unsigned n ) const
        { return const_cast<T&>( data()[n] ); }
};

/**
 * The implementation of foo::operator[] is useful for classes inheriting
 * with simple sequence containers like:
 *  foo<T,std::deque<T>>, foo<T,std::vector<T>>, ..
 *
 * But the following requires operator[] to be redefined:
 */

template <class T, unsigned N>
struct baz
    : public foo<T, std::deque<std::array<T,N>> > 
{
    typedef std::deque<std::array<T,N>> data_type;
    data_type m_data;

    inline const data_type& data() const 
        { return m_data; }
    inline virtual T& operator[] ( unsigned n ) const override
        { return const_cast<T&>( data()[n/N][n%N] ); }
};

int main()
{
    baz<double,3> b; // throws an error relative to foo::operator[] depsite override
}
```

---

**EDIT 1** The error:

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -Wall virtual_operator.cpp -o virtual_operator.o
virtual_operator.cpp:11:12: error: const_cast from 'const value_type' (aka 'const std::__1::array<double, 3>') to 'double &' is not allowed
                { return const_cast<T&>( data()[n] ); }
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
virtual_operator.cpp:26:8: note: in instantiation of member function 'foo<double, std::__1::deque<std::__1::array<double, 3>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::array<double, 3> > > >::operator[]'
      requested here
struct baz
       ^
1 error generated.
```

**EDIT 2** I consider this to be part of the question; if compiling fails because `foo::operator[]` is still callable in `baz`, then why does it compile fine if I *don't* declare `foo::operator[]` as virtual (ie, hiding instead of overriding)?

Comment: Can you add the error itself to the question?

Comment: Is `bar` relevant to the question at all? I think it just adds noise and makes it harder to read. You should remove it.

Comment: @Angew Is this better?

Comment: Definitely. It's 33% less template code for readers to parse and highlights the problem area better as well. I'd certainly upvote if I hadn't already done so :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that although you are only intending to call the derived `operator[]` function on `baz` instances, the compiler still needs to generate code for the base class because that function is still callable on `baz` instances. In this case, generating that code results in a type error, because you are trying to cast a `const std::array<double,3>` into a `double&`.

In order to fix this, you should have different parts of the hierarchy which define an operator which will work for all its children, like so (with non-pertainent stuff removed):

```
template <class T, class C>
struct foo
{
    inline virtual T& operator[] ( unsigned n ) const = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct bar
    : public foo<T,std::deque<T>>
{
    inline virtual T& operator[] ( unsigned n ) const override
        { return const_cast<T&>( data()[n] ); }
};

template <class T, unsigned N>
struct baz
    : public foo<T, std::deque<std::array<T,N>> >
{
    inline virtual T& operator[] ( unsigned n ) const override
        { return const_cast<T&>( data()[n/N][n%N] ); }
};
```

This way if you have any other versions you want to add later, you can derive from bar or baz and not need to define the operator per-child.

Comment: Why would it need to generate code for this specific function in the base class if it is marked as virtual and I provide an override in the child class? Is there a workaround in this case?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn It's still callable. What is preventing `baz::operator[]` from calling `return foo::operator[](n);`, or even someone from outside calling `b . foo<blah, blah>::operator[] (7)`?

Comment: @Angew Alright then, is there any workaround or should I declare the operator as pure virtual too and implement it on a per-child basis?

Comment: It would probably be best to implement the version in `foo` further down the hierarchy as `baz` does not have the same semantics as `foo`.

Comment: @TartanLlama Sounds like something you should add to the answer.

Comment: @TartanLlama I understand what you and @Angew are saying about calling the base-class method, but in that case, why does it compile fine if I _don't_ declare `foo::operator[]` as virtual (ie hiding instead of overriding)?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Because templates and members of templates are not instantiated unless they're required. A non-virtual function which is not called is not required. For a virtual function, "It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function
of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated." (C++11 14.7.1/10)

Comment: @Angew Thank you very much, it makes sense now. I would mark this as an answer, but TartanLlama should include his comment and yours I think. My question wasn't that I did not understand the error, but _why_ I was getting it.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I added some more information to the answer. Do you have any further questions?